# How can I bypass the Attribute error: 'None'?

Tags: python, html, url, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have this body of code where I am trying to extract the text from the th and td tags.

```
d = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
soup = bs(d,'lxml')
find_tr = soup.find_all('tr') #Iterates through 'tr'
for i in find_tr:
 for j in i.find_all('th'): #iterates through 'th' tags in the 'tr'
     if j is not None:
         print(j.th.text)
 for k in i.find_all('td'): #iterates through 'td' tags in 'tr'
     if k is not None:
         print(k.td.text)
```

After running, I keep getting this error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Use try except on attribute error to step over none issues:

```
for i in find_tr:
    for j in i.find_all('th'): #iterates through 'th' tags in the 'tr'
        try:
            print(j.th.text)
        except AttributeError:
            continue
    for k in i.find_all('td'): #iterates through 'td' tags in 'tr'
        try:
            print(k.td.text)
        except AttributeError:
            continue
```

Comment: I personally love the try/except approach in general.

Comment: EAFP: Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission

Comment: i just did, Nothing came out in the output.No error, nothing. just ran with no output.

Comment: If there's no output with none of the methods mentioned here, then there's something wrong for pointing out the path in the HTML code. No error output means that the exception is working and all of j/k are None's. Investigate the code once more, parsing HTML code is hard sometimes.

Comment: Maybe share the url you are looking

Answer (score 0):

You should add conditions checking that `k.td` and `j.th` are not `None`.

For example:

```
for i in find_tr:
 for j in i.find_all('th'): #iterates through 'th' tags in the 'tr'
     if j.th is not None:
         print(j.th.text)
 for k in i.find_all('td'): #iterates through 'td' tags in 'tr'
     if k.td is not None:
         print(k.td.text)
```

Comment: Nothing was printed, did this way before. Nothing came out, no error, nothing.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to Gabip's answer:

you could check if the attribute exists:

```py
class Foo:
  def __init__(self):
    self.foo = "foo text"

>>> fooObj = Foo()
>>> fooObj.text
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'O' object has no attribute 'text'
>>> dir(o)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'foo']

if "text" in dir(o):
  print("has attr")
else: 
  print("does not have attr")
# prints: "does not have attr"
```